# Circle Rasterization Algorithm - center between pixels

Tags: graphics, geometry, rasterizing, bresenham

I have a problem where I have to select all squares (think pixels) that are partially within a circle (even if the circle only cuts through a small corner of the square, but not if it goes through one of the corner vertices). The radius is an integer multiple of the pixel size.
The problem is that the center of the circle is between pixels, i.e. on the corner vertices of four pixels.
I want to visit each pixel only once.

For example, I would like to select all white pixels in the following images:

R = 8 px
[image: R = 8 px]

R = 10 px
[image: R = 10 px]

For a circle with the center in the center of a pixel, this wouldn't be a problem, and I could use the usual form of the Bresenham algorithm:

```
public void checkCircle(int x0, int y0, int radius) {
    int x = radius;
    int y = 0;
    int err = -x;

    while (x > 0) {
        while (err <= 0) {
            y++;
            err += 2 * y + 1;
        }
        checkVLine(x0 + x, y0 - y, y0 + y);
        checkVLine(x0 - x, y0 - y, y0 + y);
        x--;
        err -= 2 * x + 1;
    }
    checkVLine(x0, y0 - radius, y0 + radius);
}

public void checkVLine(int x, int y0, int y1) {
    assert(y0 <= y1);
    for (int y = y0; y <= y1; y++)
        checkPixel(x, y);
}
```

Sadly, I don't see how to adapt it to support inter-pixel circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first quadrant - cell should be marked if its **left bottom corner lies inside circle**, so you can rasterize with simple loops

```
for dy = 0 to R-1
     dx = 0
     sq = R * R - dy * dy 
     while dx * dx  < sq
        mark (dx, dy)  
        mark (dx, -dy-1)  
        mark (-dx-1, dy)  
        mark (-dx-1, -dy-1)
```

To fill whole horizontal lines, you can calculate max value for dx

```
for dy = 0 to R-1
     mdx = Floor(Sqrt(R * R - dy * dy))
     fill line (-mdx-1,dy)-(mdx,dy)
     fill line (-mdx-1,-dy-1)-(mdx,-dy-1)
```